# Display Items in a news sticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to accomplish some different thing which is something similar to the feature of news ticker. Before I ask this I tried to get it work using different different news ticker jquery plugins. But still no Luck.

This is markup I am using and let me to explain my requirement through it.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="feeds" id="feeds">
        <li class="category">category 01</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 01</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 02</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 03</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 04</li>                        
        <li class="category">category 02</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 01</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 02</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 03</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 04</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to display these list item like a news stick in a horizontal bar. How I need to display it is one category item with following two subcategory items in a row. If particular category have more than two subcategory then I need to display next two subcategory items and like wise. When displaying subcategory secondly the main category name should be still display in the row.

Finally I tried with [Jquery Advance News Ticker](http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/) plugin. It was close but not 100%

```
$('#feeds').newsTicker({
    row_height: 40,
    max_rows: 1,
    duration: 3000,
    pauseOnHover: 0
});
```

So anybody can tell me how to accomplish this with javascript or can I know is there any jquery pluging to do this.

**UPDATE :**  CSS -

```
> .container {
        background: #1e1e1e;
        height: 40px;

        .feeds {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: table;

            > li {
                display: inline-block;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-right: 50px;
                //display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding-top: 5px;
            }

            > li.category {
                background: #a11041;
                margin: 7px 30px 0;
                padding: 3px 10px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope somebody will help me out regarding this.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you change the markup? Or is that fixed? Now there no way to know which subcategories belong to which main category except for the order of the elements. Better would be to have nested UL elements, for example.
I'm not sure what your end result should look like. You say you want to show them in a horizontal bar. Do you mean the items should scroll horizontally? Do I understand correctly that there's always 1 main category and 2 subcategories visible?

Comment: i asked have you written any css for the class category-tem if yes the add it to fiddle

Comment: Yes. It should be display 1 main category and 2 subcategories

Comment: Updated my answer with CSS. @T.S. It should be scroll vertically.

Comment: Are you using less css or something

Comment: Yes I am using less css. But this a demo with CSS - http://jsbin.com/mabuloni/1/edit

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgJkm is this what you were looking for

Comment: @T.S. Can I get a help to get this work out?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an existing solution for what you want, but if you are planning on writing your own solution this may help.

It uses a somewhat different HTML structure, but I think this is what you're trying to achieve.

HTML:

```
<div id="feed">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Category 1
            <ul>
                <li>Subcategory 1</li>
                <li>Subcategory 2</li>
                <li>Subcategory 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Category 2
            <ul>
                <li>Subcategory 1</li>
                <li>Subcategory 2</li>
                <li>Subcategory 3</li>
                <li>Subcategory 4</li>
                <li>Subcategory 5</li>
                <li>Subcategory 6</li>
                <li>Subcategory 7</li>
                <li>Subcategory 8</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With CSS you make sure that the viewport (#feed) only shows one category name and two subcategories. Then, with JavaScript, you allow the user to go to the next two subcategories by changing the top or  margin-top of the sub-ul-element. If the user reached the bottom of subcategories, it goes to the next category. If the user reached the last category, it goes to the first category again.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln73X/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer. Its something close to my expecting result. Can I chat with you regarding this?

Comment: This is an [example](http://www.icc-cricket.com/) for what I exactly looking for. (Check it under main navigation bar there). Only difference is I need to display main category like red color background button there alone with 2 subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

I never get why people like to use plugins so much, it just uses a lot of space (size vise)!

anyways I had to do this a while ago, I didn't use a plugin, just pure css and jQuery. this example provides an always animating news sticker. if you want an example like the one you provided you can easily implement it, or if it is too difficult for you let me know and I'll provide you one.

first you have to set the overflow of the container to hidden in css and then put the ul inside another div (let's call it #box).

and as for your jQuery:

```
$('#box ul li:first-child').animate({marginTop:'-110px',paddingTop:'0px'},4980,'linear');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#box ul li:first-child').finish().appendTo('#box ul').css('margin-top','0px').css('padding-top','10px');
    },5000);
setInterval(function(){
    $('#box ul li:first-child').animate({marginTop:'-110px',paddingTop:'0px'},4980,'linear');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#box ul li:first-child').finish().appendTo('#box ul').css('margin-top','0px').css('padding-top','10px');
        },5000);
    },5020);
```

the marginTop in the animation should be the negative of the height of your li. (in this example it is -110px)

here is the demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ClzLy

Comment: Amin Jafari, this is not the way I am expecting.